# Not able to autowire Dao with Controller in Spring MVC

Tags: java

****Hi All I am trying to create simple login application with Spring MVC. While running my application I am getting the below exception which is saying its not able to autowire Dao.****

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'helloController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public com.dao.loginDao com.controller.HelloController.dao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dao' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-web-servlet.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframeenter code herework/dao/DataAccessException
```

**below is my controller class**

```
package com.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import com.beans.Customer;
import com.dao.loginDao;;

@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @Autowired
     private loginDao loginDao;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printWelcome(ModelMap model) {
            //  System.out.println("***********8888 controller *************************");
        model.addAttribute("message", "Hi you are successfully logged in");
        return "hello";

    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String varifyLogin(ModelMap model , @RequestParam String userId , @RequestParam String password) {

        Customer customer = loginDao.login(userId, password);
        System.out.println("***********8888 controller *************************");
        model.addAttribute("message", "welcome to Spring MVC");
        return "welcome";
    }
}
```

**Please see Dao class below:-**

```
package com.dao;
import com.beans.*;

import org.springframework.jdbc.core.BeanPropertyRowMapper;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;  
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class loginDao {

    JdbcTemplate template;  

    public void setTemplate(JdbcTemplate template) {  
        this.template = template;}

    public Customer login(String userId, String password){
        String sql="select * from Customer where CUSTOMER_ID=?";  
        Customer customer =  template.queryForObject(sql, new Object[]{userId},new BeanPropertyRowMapper<Customer>(Customer.class));  
        if(customer != null && customer.getPassword().equals(password))
        {
            return customer;
        }
        return null;
        //template.
    }
}
```

**below is my spring.xml where I have mentioned beans definition:-**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.controller" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.dao"/>


    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

     <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" autowire="byName">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"></property>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:ORCL"></property>
        <property name="username" value="SHAKTI_ELE"></property>
        <property name="password" value="root"></property>
    </bean>

<bean id="jt" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">  
<property name="dataSource" ref="ds"></property>  
</bean>  

<bean id="dao" class="com.dao.loginDao">  
<property name="template" ref="jt"></property>  
</bean>  
</beans>
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: And: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Also almost every link from this site: http://idownvotedbecau.se/. So all in all, please [edit] your question. Post some code, e.g. that from the class which can't be autowired. Add some information, currently we just have an error log. We can't help you if you don't help us understand your problem

Answer (score 0):

use Qualifier with Autowired :-

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("dao")
private loginDao loginDao;
```

Comment: it didn't work for me Vishal, any other suggestion please?

Comment: please send where you get problem?